# Android PhoneGap - Control when to show notification

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on android phone-gap chat application. It's a non native app. I want to display notifications to user only when the user not in the chat room for which the notification was sent. I.e. I need to control when the device should show notification and when not. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest yo use this plugin for push notifications (it has a good readme):

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Than in javascript you can detect if the app is in foreground or background when the notification arrives with the parameter returned by 'notification'

```
push.on('notification', function(data){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data)); //to see the data object returned on device
});
```

Comment: I am using PhoneGap Push Plugin. But this notification event is only fired when u click on the notification. My requirement is if the user is in a chat room and a notification is received for that chat room, the device should not  show the notification at all

Comment: yes indeed, if the app is in background the event is fired when user taps on the notification, but if the app is in the foreground the notification won't appear in the devices notification area and the same event gets fired.

Comment: Thanks Nagy. I had set "forceShow" to true in android config. So I was getting the notifications when the app was in foreground. Now I have set "forceShow" to false and introduced custom in-app notification when the app is in foreground. So now I can control when to show in-app notifications and when not.

Comment: In-app notifications were working fine for us till we figured out that if user in device settings (i.e. phone settings) turns off push notifications, notifications are still being received on device and notification event is being fired. That means in-app notifications are being displayed whilst in device settings push notification are turned off. Now how to fix this?

Comment: i didn't noticed this error, perhaps check if it has anything to do with this forceShow option